# HDMI on AMD video card doesn't work with sound on Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Hello today I just booted up my pc normally and the sound output is dummy output, I even reinstalled my whole OS because of that and it didn't work. This is the logs that come up during startup:

```
18:52:49 systemd: Failed to start Notification regarding a crash report.
16:35:28 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
16:35:25 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
16:35:19 pipewire-pulse: pw.conf: execvp error 'pactl': No such file or directory
16:35:19 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
16:34:54 systemd: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
16:34:52 pipewire-pulse: pw.conf: execvp error 'pactl': No such file or directory
16:34:28 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c01 failed: -110
16:34:26 kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: no codecs initialized
16:34:26 kernel: hdaudio hdaudioC1D0: no AFG or MFG node found
```

Comment: Same issue with an RX6700 XT.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a kernel issue; I've consolidated the various reports under [LP: #2009136](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2009136) and we're currently bisecting the kernel to find the root cause. I'd recommend just booting -32 until a fix is implemented

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Radeon RX 6400 hooked up to a TV. Sound was working yesterday, and is broken today. I think it is due to a kernel update. When booting with the newest kernel installed (5.19.0-35-generic) the AMD sound device does not show up in the sound settings. But when I boot using the older kernel installed on the system (5.19.0-32-generic) I'm able to choose the AMD audio device in the sound settings and sound works.

Comment: I can confirm that booting with the older kernel makes the sound work again.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.10
Kernel 5.19.0-38
HDMI does not appear in sound card settings
.
at the same time when viewing in the terminal it is.

Updated to the kernel to 6.2.10, for the sake of interest, the sound appeared immediately.

Perhaps there are problems with the config5.19.0.38 file when building the kernel.

Comment: You have installed a kernel that has not been test or approved for use at this time. It is considered a test kernel and may cause you issues with updates.